# Cannot update Java Swing ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

Here is my entire code, Main class and WarGame class, sorry if its really messy. :( I'm trying to get ImageIcon to Update everytime Button is clicked.

This is a War Card game, Everytime button is clicked it should update the picture.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WarGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
 static boolean y = true;
 static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 static String suit1;
 static String suit2;
 static String Card1;
 static String Card2;
 static int Player1Wins = 0;
 static int Player2Wins = 0;
  JLabel Player1Card;
  JLabel Player2Card;
  JLabel vs;
  JLabel player1Icon;
  JLabel player2Icon;
private ImageIcon img1;
private  ImageIcon img2;
  private JButton draw;
 String player1Show;
 String player2Show;

 int f;
 int d;
 int j;
 int k;


 public WarGame(){
     setName("WarGame");
     setLayout(null);
     setSize(350,200);

     setVisible(true);
     Player1Card = new JLabel("Player One:");
     Player1Card.setBounds(10,10, 100, 50);
     add(Player1Card);
     Player2Card = new JLabel("Player Two:");
     Player2Card.setBounds(155,10, 100, 50);
     add(Player2Card);
     vs = new JLabel("V.S");
     vs.setBounds(125,70, 100, 50);
     add(vs);
     j = 0;
     k = 0;
     f = 0;
     d= 0;
     draw = new JButton("Draw");
        draw.addActionListener(this);
        draw.setBounds(100,135, 100, 30);
        add(draw);

 }





public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == draw) {



                 f = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
                 d = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
                if (f == 1 ){
                     suit1 = "Clubs";
                }else if (f == 2){
                     suit1 = "Spades";
                }else if (f == 3){
                     suit1 = "Hearts";
                }else if (f == 4){
                   suit1 = "Diamonds";
                }

                if (d == 1 ){
                     suit2 = "Clubs";
                }else if (d == 2){
                     suit2 = "Spades";
                }else if (d == 3){
                     suit2 = "Hearts";
                }else if (d == 4){
                   suit2 = "Diamonds";
                }


                 j = 2 + (int)(Math.random()*13);
                k = 2 + (int)(Math.random()*13);

               int player1 = j;
               int player2 = k;

               if (j == 11){
                  Card1 = "Jack";
               }else if (j == 12){
                   Card1 = "Queen";
               }else if (j == 13){    
                   Card1 = "King";
               }else if (j == 3){
                   j = 6;
               }
               if (k == 11){
                      Card2 = "Jack";
               }else if (k == 12){
                       Card2 = "Queen";
               }else if (k == 13){    
                       Card2 = "King";
               }else if ( k == 3){
                   k = 6;
               }

               if (j == 0){
                   j = 2;
               }
               if (j == 14){
                   Card1 = "Ace";
               }
               if (k == 0){
                   k = 2;
               }
               if (k == 14){
                   Card2 = "Ace";
               }


               if (j <= 10 && j >= 2){
                   System.out.println("Player 1: " + j + " of " + suit1);
                   player1Show = j + suit1;

               }

               if (k <= 10 && k >= 2){
                  System.out.println("Player 2: " + k  + " of " + suit2);
                  player2Show = k+suit2;

               }
               if (j >= 11 || j == 1 ){
                   System.out.println("Player 1: " + Card1 + " of " + suit1);
                   player1Show = Card1 + suit1;

               }
               if (k >= 11 || k == 1){
                    System.out.println("Player 2: " + Card2  + " of " + suit2);
                    player2Show = Card2 + suit2;


               }

               img1 = new ImageIcon("src//decks2//" + player1Show + ".png");
                player1Icon = new JLabel();
                player1Icon.setIcon(img1);
                img2 = new ImageIcon("src//decks2//" + player2Show + ".png");
                player2Icon = new JLabel();
                player2Icon.setIcon(img2);

                player1Icon.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 100);
                player2Icon.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 100);
                add(player1Icon);
                add(player2Icon);

                if (player1 > player2){
                    System.out.println("Player 1 Wins The War");
                    Player1Wins ++;
                }else if (player2 > player1){
                   System.out.println("Player 2 Wins The War");
                   Player2Wins ++;
                }else{
                   System.out.println("The War Is A Tie");
                }
                System.out.println("Player 1 Wins: " + Player1Wins + "  Player2 Wins: " + Player2Wins );


                   if(Player1Wins < Player2Wins){
                       System.out.println("Congratulations! Player 2 Wins with a score of " + Player2Wins + " to " + Player1Wins);
                   }else if (Player1Wins > Player2Wins){
                       System.out.println("Congratulations! Player 1 Wins with a score of " + Player1Wins + " to " + Player2Wins);
                   }else if (Player1Wins == Player2Wins){
                       System.out.println("Oops! Its a tie!" + Player1Wins + " to " + Player2Wins);
                   }





        }

             revalidate();    
         repaint();
    }




}
```

---

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WarGame s = new WarGame();
    s.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: adding 
revalidate();    
repaint();
did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding/removing components. Try to add these to the end of your `actionPerformed()`

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     ...

     add(player1Icon); 
     add(player2Icon);

     ...

     revalidate();    
     repaint();
 }
```

See [revalidate() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29)

**Edit:**

It's hard for me to replicate your problem from my end because I don't have the card images, but try this. At the top where you declare your card image labels, instantiate them too. `JLabel player1Icon = new JLabel();`. In `WarGame` constructor, add those labels. In your `actionPerformed`, take out the `add(player1Icon)` and the `player1show = new JLabel()` and just leave the `player1show.setIcon()`

Comment: Can you post running code that we can use to try and help fix your problem.

Comment: Done. Edited main post

Comment: So you let me get this straight. You can get the first image to show, but after that, you can't get another image to show? Or you can't get any images to show at all?

Comment: The first Image displays, but the ones after that do not. For example
First time button is clicked:
ace of hearts - Displayed
2 of Spades - Displayed
Second time:
nothing is displayed, same pictures are there even tho numbers change

Comment: Is it just supposed to be one card for each player, or do the cards add up, meaning when you draw again, two images show up for each player?

Comment: One card for each player, here is what it looks like after TWO clicks: http://puu.sh/5Dh7V.png

Comment: It's hard for me to replicate your problem from my end because I don't have the card images, but try this. At the top where you declare your card image labels, instantiate them too. `JLabel player1show = new JLabel();`. `WarGame` constructor, add those labels. In your `actionPerformed`, take out the `add(player1show)` and the `player1show = new JLabel()` and just leave the `player1show.setIcon()`

Comment: Sorry, I meand the player1Icon, whatever is the labels that are holding the icons.

Comment: What was i suppose to do in the WarGame Constructor? I removed the add(player1Icon) and no images show up now

Comment: you need to `add(player1Icon); add(player2Icon);` in the constructor